# Unable to install any package in computer at my office, how to fix?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to use computer in my office for working using Rstudio because I realised that there is Rstudio installed in the computer. However, when I'm trying to install the package I need, the package is unable to install. I try so many package but the same issue happen.Even though, I'm trying to update installed package such as rlang version 1.02 to the latest one, it is also failed.  I've tried to restart Rstudio as well after I installed the package, but I can't find the package that I have installed before.

Here is the error message that I receive when I try to install the very standard one such as scales package:

```
install.packages("scales")
also installing the dependencies ‘rlang’, ‘lifecycle’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
          binary source needs_compilation
rlang      1.0.2  1.0.6              TRUE
lifecycle  1.0.1  1.0.2             FALSE
scales     1.2.0  1.2.1             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/rlang_1.0.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1718546 bytes (1.6 MB)
downloaded 1.6 MB

package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\axk1076\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYjc7m3\downloaded_packages
installing the source packages ‘lifecycle’, ‘scales’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lifecycle_1.0.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 102178 bytes (99 KB)
downloaded 99 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/scales_1.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 270609 bytes (264 KB)
downloaded 264 KB

'\\adf\storage\A\K\AXK1076'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
* installing *source* package 'lifecycle' ...
** package 'lifecycle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.5 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'lifecycle'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/library/lifecycle'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status
'\\adf\storage\A\K\AXK1076'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'scales'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/library/scales'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘scales’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\axk1076\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYjc7m3\downloaded_packages’
```

I don't know how Rstudio installed in this computer and I'm truly beginner in R. Is there anyone can help me? thank you in advance. Regards.

Comment: It looks like you have version 4.0.3. Update R to the latest version (4.2.1) and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not known how R was installed in your computer, I would highly recommend you to uninstall both R and RStudio and installing the latest versions from the official websites.

1. First install R from: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/
2. Install RStudio from: https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/

Maybe they were installed in the wrong settings for your computer. Also to prevent bigger issues in the future (especially for beginners), that's the best option.

Comment: The problem is I don't have the access to install or uninstall anything in the computer

Comment: Then you'll need to contact whoever has those admin powers.